# Trying to use Thread.sleep function, catch token has multiple errors

Tags: java, try-catch

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class HelloWorld 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner math = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is 2 + 2?");
        int num = math.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Wrong."); // Displays "Wrong." no matter the answer.

        {
            Thread.sleep(2000); // Adds a timer for 2 seconds.
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Please, try again :-)");
            }

        int num1 = math.nextInt();
        System.out.println(""); //Displays some message.
    }
}
```

The code is supposed to display "What is 2 + 2?", a user inputs an answer, the code returns "Wrong." no matter what the answer. After a 2 second pause, the code displays "Please, try again :-)" and a user inputs an integer and the code returns a message.

The errors occur on the line with the catch token. The errors are: 
Syntax error on token "catch", ( expected,
Syntax error, insert "-> LambdaBody" to complete LambdaExpression,
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment,
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

Comment: where is the `try` for the catch ?

Comment: A `catch` block needs a `try` block before it. You are missing the `try`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a `catch` in java you need to have a `try`. It is called a `try..catch` block. Please read the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

So, adding a `try` as follows should get rid of the errors you are asking about here :

```
    System.out.println("Wrong."); // Displays "Wrong." no matter the answer.
    try // Looks like you missed the try here
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000); // Adds a timer for 2 seconds.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Please, try again :-)");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant see try block. you can use this way also without try catch. Main method can throw InterruptedException ...

```
 public class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            Scanner math = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is 2 + 2?");
            int num = math.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Wrong."); // Displays "Wrong." no matter the answer.

            {
                Thread.sleep(2000); // Adds a timer for 2 seconds.
            }

            int num1 = math.nextInt();
            System.out.println(""); //Displays some message.
        }
    }
```